# How to initialize the status of a CRD in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I have created a [CRD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) in my Kubernetes environment. The CRD has a corresponding [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/). The operator will update the CRD's field `.status.serviceState` for the users to know the current state of the underlying service. The value of the field `.status.serviceState` could be one of "PENDING", "READY", "ERROR".

I wonder if there's a way to automatically initialize the field `.status.serviceState` to be "PENDING" when the CRD is created. Although I can do the initialization in the operator, I'm worried that user might still see the field uninitialized when there's a delay of the operator.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: When associated crd of operator is not created in the cluster and user try to create operator, he will get error saying matching crd not found if its status either pending or error.   Status field is updated by K8S process.